# How to detect the overflow of the sum of all negative numbers in an array?

Tags: java, overflow

The specifications are as follows: There is an array named *X* of two's complement integers in memory. There is also a two's complement integer variable *n* which sets the size of the array. Thus *X* contains *n* elements. *n* is a 16-bit integer, the maximum size of the array is 32767 entries.

I need to calculate the summary of negative elements in array *X* and detect whether the result is a overflow or not.

```
public class BinaryArray {
    static int[]X = {3, -30000, 27, 101, 50, 0, -20000, -21, 19, 6, 4, -10};
    static int n = 12;
    static int negSum = 0;
    static int pzCount = 0;
    static int oddCount = 0;
    static boolean overflow = false;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
            if(X[i] < 0) {
                negSum +=X[i];
            }
            if(X[i] >= 0) {
                pzCount++;
            }
            if(X[i] >0 && X[i] % 2 !=0) {
                oddCount++;
            }
        }
        
        if(negSum > 0) {
            overflow = true;
        }
        
        System.out.println("Array negSum: " + negSum);
        System.out.println("Array pzCount: " + pzCount);
        System.out.println("Array oddCount: " + oddCount);
        
        if (overflow) {
            System.out.println("Overflow indicator: 1");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Overflow indicator: 0");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried big numbers that must cause a overflow but my code runs as no. I wonder if I'm judging the overflow in the wrong way?

Comment: Can you, please, edit the question to show the "big numbers" you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "big numbers"?  Did you try numbers near `Integer.MIN_VALUE`?

Comment: You should test for overflow within loop (after each add) since overflow can "wrap around": For example `negSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE; negSum += -2` yields overflow but then adding `negSum += Integer.MIN_VALUE` yields overflow false.

Answer (score 1):

Your test for overflow is unreliable. Consider the possibility that `negSum` overflowed / wrapped around more than once.

To reliably detect overflow in arithmetic, consider using the `~Exact` methods of the [`Math` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html).  Unlike regular arithmetic operations, these  methods throw an `ArithmeticException` when overflow occurs.

```
public class BinaryArray {

    static int[] X = {3, -30000, 27, 101, 50, 0, -20000, -21, 19, 6, 4, -10,
         -2147483647, -2147483647};
 
    static int negSum = 0;
    static int pzCount = 0;
    static int oddCount = 0;
    static boolean overflow1 = false, overflow2 = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < X.length; i++) {
            try {
                if (X[i] < 0) {
                    negSum += X[i];
                    int check = Math.addExact(negSum, X[i]);
                }
            } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
                overflow1 = true;
            }

            if (X[i] >= 0) {
                pzCount++;
            }
            if (X[i] > 0 && X[i] % 2 != 0) {
                oddCount++;
            }
        }

        if (negSum > 0) {
            overflow2 = true;
        }

        System.out.println("Array negSum: " + negSum);
        System.out.println("Array pzCount: " + pzCount);
        System.out.println("Array oddCount: " + oddCount);
        System.out.println ("Overflow indicator: " + overflow1);
        System.out.println ("Old overflow indicator: " + overflow2);
    }
}
```

I used two `boolean overflow` variables. That lets you play around with the values of the  `int X[]` and compare the results.

Off-topic: I removed the variable `n`.  That way, the `for` loop will always iterate once for each element in `X`.  Having a separate variable for the number of elements in the array increases the likelihood of creating a bug when elements need to be added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't depend on the the final value of `negSum` to detect overflow.  If two negative numbers create overflow their sum will be positive.  But what happens if the next negative number when added to that result is negative?  You had overflow, but it was hidden by subsequent negative additions. So you need to check for overflow after each negative addition.

Here is a related item you may be unaware of.

Interim overflows during the addition of numbers does not mean the final sum will be incorrect.  As long as the order of the summands could be rearranged to prevent overflow during the process, the overflow would be corrected.  Here is an example:

```
int sum1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE + Integer.MAX_VALUE + Integer.MIN_VALUE + 
  Integer.MIN_VALUE + 10;

int sum2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE + Integer.MIN_VALUE + Integer.MAX_VALUE + 
  Integer.MIN_VALUE + 10;
 
System.out.println(sum1 + " " + sum2);
```

prints

```
8 8
```

In the first case, overflow occurred after the second addition. But subsequent additions brought the result back into the range of the target type.
In the second  case, no overflow was encountered due to the rearrangement of the values.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I need to calculate the summary of negative elements in array X and detect whether the result is a overflow or not. ..."*

Here is an example using the *[BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)* class.

```java
Random r = new Random();
int i, v, n = 1000, a[] = new int[n],
    mn = Integer.MIN_VALUE, mx = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = r.nextInt(mn, mx);
BigInteger x = BigInteger.ZERO, mb = BigInteger.valueOf(mn);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if ((v = a[i]) > 0) continue;
    if ((x = x.add(BigInteger.valueOf(v))).compareTo(mb) < 0)
        break;
}
if (i != n) System.out.println("overflow at " + i);
```

Output

```
overflow at 5
```

And, here is the same example, with an output for each iteration.

```java
Random r = new Random();
int i, v, n = 1000, a[] = new int[n],
    mn = Integer.MIN_VALUE, mx = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = r.nextInt(mn, mx);
BigInteger x = BigInteger.ZERO, mb = BigInteger.valueOf(mn);
System.out.printf("%4s%12s   %12s   %s%n", "i", "x", "v", "sum");
System.out.println("-".repeat(45));
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if ((v = a[i]) > 0) continue;
    System.out.printf("%4s%12s + %12s = ", i, x, v);
    x = x.add(BigInteger.valueOf(v));
    System.out.println(x);
    if (x.compareTo(mb) < 0) break;
}
if (i != n) System.out.println("overflow at " + i);
```

Output

```
   i           x              v   sum
---------------------------------------------
   1           0 +    -20935943 = -20935943
   7   -20935943 +   -914825338 = -935761281
   8  -935761281 +  -1732178540 = -2667939821
overflow at 8
```